# Stop mouse from waking Windows PC

Tags: mouse, sleep, wake-up

I know others have asked this exact question, but I have read the answers on those posts, and not found anything which solves the problem for me.

My laptop will wake from sleep when the mouse is moved. My goal is for nothing to be able to wake the computer except pressing the power button.

In Event Viewer, it sates:
"The system is exiting Modern Standby
Reason: Input Mouse."

- There is no setting in BIOS for waking the computer on mouse, keyboard, or USB input
- powercfg lastwake shows "Wake History Count - 0"
- powercfg -devicequery wake_armed shows "NONE"
- I have checked **every single device** in Device Manager and none of them have the box checked for "Allow this device to wake the computer"

I did check keyboard, HID, and **literally** every single entry in Device Manager, including showing all Hidden Devices and checking them too.

Probably not related (I hope), but just in case... I also have found in the middle of the night the computer will wake itself and put itself back to sleep repeatedly. Event viewer shows "Entering Modern Standy" and "Exiting Modern Standy" with the exact same timestamp to the second. This recurs several times over a short period of time, and then in the morning I cannot get the computer to wake or display anything until I hard power it off and back on. Whenever this happens, event viewer says the reason for exiting Modern Standby is "Reason: Input Mouse". Exactly the same as if I put it to sleeep and accidentally wake it with the mouse. Also, I live alone, no pets, so it is not possible the mouse was actually moved when that odd behavior happens.

Comment: Probably I have to say good luck. Mouse wakes up computer by built in design. I handle this as follows for a laptop:  Turn off mouse, close lid, travel, open lid, turn on mouse.

Comment: If the OP has a wireless mouse, turning the power off on that device should prevent a wake-up call.

Comment: Yes, just turning off the mouse works fine as well.

Comment: Is sleep the right thing? Perhaps hibernate instead?

Comment: Due to other issues I have configured my desktop to do a full hibernate - moving the mouse doesn't wake it - however clicking a mouse button does.

Comment: Do you have a gaming mouse ? If so you may want to reduce the sensitivity in the driver and increase it in windows (to keep the same overall speed) - if gaming mice have their sensitivity cranked they can suffer from Jitter - artificial movements that aren't real.